# How can I add my own .js and .css to any page in magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.4

I am looking to design my own customisation on home page and i want to customise it with my own looks. I have a css file and i would also like to add some jquery functionality to it. So how can i add these files to my home page. eg without magento I would have done it in this way

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="myscript.js"> </SCRIPT>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="looks.css" />
```

Now I am not able to do the same in Magento. Is there a way to do So ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via cms.xml layout of your theme. It should be done inside `cms_index_index` handle like

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>js/yourscript.js</script></action>
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/looks.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Would be better done in local.xml under the custom theme's layout folder.

Comment: @Zifius & Ben :- How if i directly use it inside my phtml file.. As i have done that and it is working fine... Do it have any side effects.

Comment: @Ben Agreed, wrote this before having my morning coffee :)

Comment: @Showket this is called 'bad practice' and we are involving you in the way it meant to be done :)

Comment: Thanks for ur precious response, I will be really greatful to you if you can tell me why it will be a bad practice...?

Comment: @Showket Ok, I will try to explain. The system has some conventions how things should be built. It might seem that doing it via layouts is a more cumbersome way but in the long shot it will be convenient for example for the other developers who will modify your code. Also you've said you need to include files on home page only. So perhaps you are modified the other file, not head.phtml. What if you need to add it to `<head>` and after the other scripts included?

Comment: Also, by using the system you get benefits like multi-file concatenation speeding up your site.

Comment: Agree with Zifius, especially with regards to the concatenation if you add your script to the items in the html_head block via the layout. It should be noted though that the opcheckout.js file is added in a phtml file, so one could argue either point. I think the layout XML is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add Zifius's example into the particular cms page Layout Update XML textfield(Design Tab under CMS/Pages/pagename). Might make it easier to change when there is a strict deployment process in place and you don't want to bother with syncing your repos and deploying the changes.